# Easy way for converting request body to xml (Rest assured) API

Tags: java, json, xml, rest-assured

I'm Java beginner. Just added JSON. Simple dependency and it's so easy to convert data to JSON format.

example :

```
public void Post_test3_positive(){
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
    user.put("name","John");
    user.put("email","John@inbox.lv");
    
    given()
            .body(user.toJSONString())
            .when().post("/api/user/createUserPost")
            .then().statusCode(201)
```

Is there any easy way to convert request body (username and email ) to XML format?

Thanks

Comment: Underscore-java has a static method U.jsonToXml(json).

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this to convert map to xml string :

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("name","chris");
        map.put("island","faranga");

        XStream magicApi = new XStream();
        magicApi.registerConverter(new MapEntryConverter());
        magicApi.alias("root", Map.class);

        String xml = magicApi.toXML(map);
        System.out.println("Result of tweaked XStream toXml()");
        System.out.println(xml);

        Map<String, String> extractedMap = (Map<String, String>) magicApi.fromXML(xml);
        assert extractedMap.get("name").equals("chris");
        assert extractedMap.get("island").equals("faranga");

    }

    public static class MapEntryConverter implements Converter {

        public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
            return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
        }

        public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {

            AbstractMap map = (AbstractMap) value;
            for (Object obj : map.entrySet()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) obj;
                writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
                Object val = entry.getValue();
                if ( null != val ) {
                    writer.setValue(val.toString());
                }
                writer.endNode();
            }

        }

        public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while(reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
                reader.moveDown();

                String key = reader.getNodeName(); // nodeName aka element's name
                String value = reader.getValue();
                map.put(key, value);

                reader.moveUp();
            }

            return map;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use java POJO and convert it to json/xml by using Jackson library.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
@NoArgsConstructor
static class Example {
    private String name;
    private String email;
}

@Test
void name() {
    Example payload = new Example("John", "John@inbox.lv");

    given().log().body()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(payload)
            .when().post("https://postman-echo.com/post");

    given().log().body()
            .contentType(ContentType.XML)
            .body(payload)
            .when().post("https://postman-echo.com/post");

}
```

result:

```
Body:
{
    "name": "John",
    "email": "John@inbox.lv"
}
Body:
<example>
  <email>John@inbox.lv</email>
  <name>John</name>
</example>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```